# pausing an animation at a particular time and resuming

Tags: css

I want the square to start playing the animation for 5s then, stop playing the animation for 3s and then continue. Is this possible only using CSS3?

```css
.box {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: you can use `animation-delay` property. If you want to delay the animation at first like `animation-delay: 3s`. It will delay the animation for about 3 second.

Comment: @AhmedAli I want the square to stop in the middle of animation, not in the beginning itself. cheers :)

Comment: You can use more multiple keyframes to just stop the cube at some specific angle. Indeed the animation will be running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since **animation-duration** is 20s, then in the **@kayframes**, 25% = 5s => 5% = 1s => 15% = 3s (between 25% - 40%)

```css
.box {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: rotate 20s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```